# Реализация подгружаемых панелей

Tags: java, swing

Задался таким вопросом.
А правильно ли я стараюсь проектировать ГУИ?
Сейчас делаю приложение на Swing. 
Есть один `JFrame`, в нем выставлена `setContentPane` таких же размеров `JPanel`.
Потом на эту `JPanel` по клику на кнопку грузится другая `JPanel`, потом определенные действия, последняя `JPanel` исчезает, появляется новая и так далее.
Представьте себе кнопочку "Далее".
Сейчас я делаю так:
я передаю в конструктор предыдущую панель, потом, когда она мне не нужна была, вызывал метод "самоудаляйся и грузи другое" и так далее. 
Я сейчас говорю только об уровне View.

**Мне сегодня посоветовали, а почему бы не сделать подгружаемые панели Singleton и статическими?
Это хорошая практика, это лучшая практика, это не очень хорошая практика? Если кто сможет, парочку аргументов...**

Спасибо!

Comment: наверно, хорошая практика, получается, что все вьюхи в памяти и не создаются повторно + контроль их кол-ва

Answer (score 1):

Если таких элементов много `JPanel`, `JButton` и проч., то надо задуматься об их кэшировании.

Кэш обычно реализуется в паттерне Singleton - то есть некий статический класс (или статический объект класса) содержащий в себе конечный список элементов подлежащих кэшированию. Имеет методы добавления в кэш и выдачи из кэша. Кэш имеет внутри небольшой тредик, который с некоторой частотой проверяет когда в последний раз использовался тот или иной объект. Если он не использовался давно то "убивает" его. Соответственно при выдаче из кэша, если объекта в кэше нет через конструктор создаем и выдаем.

В общем это такой некий бест-практис - позволяет найти разумный компромисс между сохранением в памяти всех объектов (соответственно его загрязнением) и скоростью выдачи.

Comment: Нет, елементов интерфейса не оч много, а если по сути?
Спасибо!

Comment: Ну тогда сделайте в паттерне Singleton - это нормально

Comment: @Barmaley, кэш? например?

Comment: @Gorets - не понял вопроса

Comment: пример такого кэша можно? т.е. реализации вот этого момента "Кэш имеет внутри небольшой тредик, который с некоторой частотой проверяет когда в последний раз использовался тот или иной объект. Если он не использовался давно то "убивает" его. Соответственно при выдаче из кэша, если объекта в кэше нет через конструктор создаем и выдаем." неогда раньше не встречал такого

Comment: @Gorets например смотри сюда: http://www.christianschenk.org/blog/implementing-a-simple-cache-with-java/